# what is the type of collection object on which iterable is used in the Reduce method of a MapReduce Program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to understand the usage of Iterable in the reduce method of the Reducer in a MapReduce program. The signature of the method is

```
protected void reduce(KEYIN key,
                      Iterable<VALUEIN> values,
                      org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
               throws IOException,
                      InterruptedException
```

My question is about the Iterable values. Is the values a List type, Set type ?. Just curious. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a customized iterator over data on disk- why not looking at the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the types in the VALUES can be any type that implements the Writable interface.  For example, IntWritable, LongWritable, Text, etc.  These are in the org.apache.hadoop.io package.  And you can create your own.

This definition is telling you that your implementation of the reduce() method is going to be called with 2 arguments: a key (of a parameterized type), and a collection of values (also of a parameterized type).  The collections implementation is hidden from you; you don't care how its collected.  But the call gives you access to that collection via the Iterable interface, which simple means you can use a  `for (VALUEIN val: values)` loop to iterate thru the values one-at-a-time.

For example, lets say you implement a reducer that takes a LongWritable key and Text values.  Your reduce method is going to look like this:

```
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values){...
...
for (Text word: values) {
   ...do something with word...
}
```

You'll notice that the values argument does not provide you with a size() method, so you can't say values.size() and get the number of values in the collection.  Thats because you are dealing with a potentially gargantuan collection of values whose length is indeterminant.  This is big data, baby!